# Disable printScreen in windows 7 when connected firom ubuntu 16

Tags: remote-desktop

I have disabled printScreen in windows through Group policy, but when i am trying to connect from ubuntu machine (through RDP) again screenshot is functioning. So Want to disable PrintScreen option in ubuntu. 
It should get disabled even though when i connect windows from ubuntu through RDP and when connecting from windows to windows through RDP print screen is not functioning which is working as expected.

Please can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: So the question is going to be, is the print screen functioning on the windows machine, or is the print screen in Ubuntu taking a picture of the RDP client?

Comment: In Windows server Print Screen is Completely disabled, But When Connecting From Ubuntu Machine through RDP again Print Screen is working. but what i want is if Connect form Ubuntu through RDP PrintScreen should not Work.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to prohibit screen capture in Ubuntu due to how the X11 protocol (that takes care of graphics display) works. Either you give a user access to the displayed graphics in whatever way they wish or you don't.

On another note, a user can just take a photography of the screen if they can't or don't want to use the screen capture feature.